# Issues with Convergence of Finite Difference Method on Uniform Grid

Tags: finite-differences, poissons-equation, finite-difference-methods

I've written some code that carries out the central finite difference equation to solve this poisson system:

$\Delta u(x,y) = f, u(x,y) = g$ in domain $[0,1]^2$.

where $u(x,y) = \cos(4) \cos(4)$  (and hence $\Delta u = -32\pi^2\cos(4) \cos(4)$)

I get this contour plot of my results:[image: Contour plot for N=64 Grid points]

And for some reason I have an increasing gridpoint L2 norm as N increases. I know my code is correct as when I test it with any other similar function I get a smooth contour as expected. Would anyone be able to shine some light on what could be going on?

Comment: How are you calculating the L2 norm?

Comment: I'm calculating the gridpoint L2 norm $=\sqrt{sum{i}  f^2_i \Delta x}$ where $f_i$  = $estimate_i-exact_i$.